# How can generate Zebra's label to printer?

Tags: android, barcode, zebra-printers

I develope an app that read data from Filemaker to android. But now, I don't know to generate label for Zebra's printer (Zebra Gk420T). I create file .png with text and barcode, but I don't understand how send it to printer. Also, there are other method to generate label?

```
connection = new TcpConnection("192.168.51.105", 9100);

connection.open();
if(connection.isConnected()) {
   ZebraPrinter printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(connection);
   ZebraImageI image = ZebraImageFactory.getImage(bitEtichetta);
   ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(connection).printImage(image, 0, 0, 300, 250, false);
   connection.close();
}
```

Comment: Show some code. This site is for saying what you want to do, what you have tried, and then asking about a problem you ran into. Also, how is this device different than any other printer-type device? How are you expecting to connect to this device? Put these details into the body of the question.

Comment: @jdv now,, why connection is not open?

Comment: Only you can answer this.